# Why I'm getting "sh" calling "echo $0" inside bash inside php exec?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, exec

I have code like this:

```
public function shell($code) {
    $code = preg_replace('/"/', '\\"', $code);
    exec('bash -c "' . $code . '"', $result);
    return $result;
}
```

and when I call `shell("echo $0");` I'm getting sh instead of bash, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original shell is expanding the variable inside doublequotes. To prevent variable expansion, use single quotes:

```
exec("bash -c '" . $code . "'", $result);
```